# Simcard not recognized iPhone 3GS iOS 6.1.6

Tags: upgrade, ios, iphone

I've updated my jailbroken iPhone 3GS via iTunes restore to iOS 6.1.6, but after the update I am not able to activate my iPhone and its showing **no service**.

It says **no sim card is installed in the device which you are activating**, although it is inserted.

My iPhone is stuck on the activation page and I cannot use the iPhone because activation is required.

Comment: Does it work with a different SIM?

Comment: I have already tried it 4-5 times, even by removing sim card and inserting it again and switching on the device again, but still doesnt recognize and activate. My iphone 3gs is from US and I am using it India since 2 and half years, till now my sim card was working in it. Only after the update of my jailbroken device to ios 6.1.6 by restoring factory settings, its happining. Is it because my sim card is of INDIA or so, will i have to break my sim card or phone lock for that.

Comment: My iphone 3gs is from US and I am using it India since 2 and half years, till now my sim card was working in it. Only after the update of my jailbroken device to ios 6.1.6 by restoring factory settings, its happining. Is it because my sim card is of INDIA or so, will i have to break my sim card or phone lock for that.

Comment: Have you tried to revert to an officially supported build of iOS on the phone? Reverting the jailbreak? The 3GS only officially supports up to iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

**Remove the Simcard and place it back**, get a paperclip to do this for an iPhone 3GS.

Try it (several times if it does not recognize it after one try) and it should recognize the simcard.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the SIM card and insert it again. If it's doesn't help, try to restore the device again.